# Wifi connected but cannot access internet, ubuntu

Tags: wireless

I can connect to Wifi network.
I can even do `ping 8.8.8.8` 
But i cannot ping `www.google.com` can't access anywhere.
But wifi is working and can get internet access with other wifi networks. The problem is in a specific wifi connection.Please help..

Comment: @ptetteh227 Since that will often help with situations like this, it seems reasonable to have an answer about it. Would you be willing to post such an answer? (You [might also want to mention](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) `8.8.4.4`, though that could be added afterwards.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more permanent solution use the [google public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) (thanks to @Eliah) instead of your ISP DNS:

First lets replace the resolv.conf symlink with a static file:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo touch /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then edit the new file:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

and paste at the top of the file

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

save the file with **ctrl+o** and exit the editor with **ctrl+x**

at this point pinging www.google.com should work

We should then prevent any editing of the resolv file:

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

In the future if you want to make the resolv.conf file writable again do:

```
sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on /etc/resolv.conf

I'm getting this..

Comment: i'll edit my answer.