# Can't connect to a specefic WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless

I was playing around with something in Ubuntu and the only thing related to networks I touched is changing DNS. But I corrected that later. Now, this specific WiFi is getting connected, but the internet is not working with it.

And all the other WiFis are working fine. I have tried all the things available on the internet including [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028651/wifi-connected-but-cannot-access-internet-ubuntu), but nothing seems to help.

Pinging to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 fails.
All the other devices's WiFi is working fine.

**Just after rebooting it(Internet from this WiFi), it ran for about 1-2 Seconds**, but then it showed

> DNS address couldn't be found

and

> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET.

Comment: Could you ping 8.8.8.8? Could you ping google.com? What does it show?

Comment: It doesn't ping. when I stop it using ctrl C it shows 100% packet loss.

Comment: 8.8.8.8 also couldn't? What does iwconfig, ifconfig, ip -a show?

Comment: yes 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 also.

Comment: Have you tried to connect using other device? Edit your question and add these details please

Comment: please have a look now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it solved. I tried many things from changing DNS to configuring networks file like resolve.conf. But in the end, what worked is changing the MAC CHANGER.

```
sudo ip link set dev wlp2s0 down
sudo macchanger -r wlp2s0
sudo ip link set dev wlp2s0 up
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and it was caused by nearby devices. The signals of my WiFi device were less than the other device and channel was also same. You need to **change it's channel**.

Follow these steps to solve your issue:

1. Connect your mobile with Wifi by going near to your Wifi or connect laptop with eathernet cable.
2. Open any web browser and go to **device configuration menu** by typing default gateway address(that is usually written on the back side of WiFi device).
3. Go to wireless settings>advanced-settings and find the option to change WiFi channel.
   You can also search how to change channel for your WiFi model.
4. Change WiFi Channel and apply.
5. Forget WiFi from laptop and reconnect.
   enjoy:)

Comment: I could try it. but this is my hostel wifi and I don't know admincredentials. management doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your mobile with Wifi by going near to your Wifi or connect laptop with eathernet cable.
Open any web browser and go to device configuration menu by typing default gateway address(that is usually written on the back side of WiFi device).
Go to wireless settings>advanced-settings and find the option to change WiFi channel. You can also search how to change channel for your WiFi model.
Change WiFi Channel and apply.
Forget WiFi from laptop and reconnect. enjoy:)

Comment: Hey, did you just copied the same from the above answer?

Comment: Yes cause I agree with that answer

Comment: You can simply upvote my answer if you liked it.